# writing a list of points in a list of files

Tags: python-3.x

I have 100 points and I want to devide them to 10 different groups bades on their distance from 10 reference points and write each group in a file. 
I write my program as:

```
from numpy import *
from math import *
from time import *
a=1.0
b=1.0
nx=10     # number of mesh in x
ny=10     # number of mesh in y
dx=a/nx
dy=b/ny
data=loadtxt("cvt_squate.txt",float)
n=data.shape

fids = []
for i in range(n[0]):
    ii=str(i)
    fids.append(open('file' + ii + '.txt', 'w'))

def calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
     dist = sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
     return dist

for i in range(nx) :
    for j in range(ny) :
        distance=10.0
        grain=1000
        x=(i+0.5)*dx
        y=(j+0.5)*dy
        for k in range (n[0]):   
            d = calculateDistance(x,y,data[k,0],data[k,1])
            if d<distance:
                distance=d
                grain=k
        print(grain)
        kk=str(grain)
        outdata = vstack((x,y)).T
        savetxt('file' + kk + 'txt', outdata)
```

But in my results, I have one point in each file instead of group of points.

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample data it's difficult to see how your code is supposed to work.  But firstly I'd recommend rewriting you imports to:

```
import numpy as np 
import math
```

I can't see where you use the time module.

if you define your results as a list outside your For k loop and append all the points which are near the reference points to this list.  Something like:

```
outdata = []
for k in range(n[0]):   
    d = calculateDistance(x,y,data[k,0],data[k,1])
    if d<distance:
        outdata.append([data[k,0],data[k,1]])
```

should get you nearer where you want to be.